# Can I upgrade to latest OS on my Macbook Air 2011?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, osx-yosemite, macbook-air

My Macbook Air 2011 is running Yosemite 10.10.5, which is the latest it can have through apple updates. But I need to install the latest Apple OS in order to build Xamarin code for iOS.

My Macbook Air is obviously old and apple doesn't support it anyways, is there a way I can somehow upgrade the latest Mac OS? It has 8 GB RM and 256 GB hdd.

Current target OS would be macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 1):

There’s a [tool](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/) that will patch many older Macs, including yours, so that Catalina can be installed. It’s obviously unsupported, and there may well be issues, especially with applications that use graphics intensively. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: You'll probably have to go to High Sierra first, to get APFS support, before Catalina. That Macbook will do HS natively, but Catalina even with dosdude's patch will need APFS first. [There's even a chance you will need to go to El Capitan before HS, but test HS first]